# Angular DevExtreme Themes

Tags: angular, themes, devextreme

I am trying to load themes for the DevExtreme widgets for angular. I have followed different approaches:

1. Set the style in angular.json but it doesn't cause any effect:

   ```
   "projects": {
   "my-project": {
     "root": "",
     "sourceRoot": "src",
     "projectType": "application",
     "architect": {
       "build": {
         "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
         "options": {
           "outputPath": "dist",
           "index": "src/index.html",
           "main": "src/main.ts",
           "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
           "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
           "assets": [
             "src/assets",
             "src/favicon.ico",
             "src/manifest.json"
           ],
           "styles": [
             "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
             "node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
             "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
             "node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css",
             "node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.dark.css",
             "src/sass/styles.scss"
           ],
   ```
2. Set it in index.html but also no effect:

   ```
   <head>
      ...
     <link rel="dx-theme" data-theme="generic.dark" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/18.2.3/css/dx.dark.css" data-active="true" />
   </head>
   ```

and set it with `DxThemes.current('generic.dark');`

3. Use the locale css files as in (2):

   ```
   <head>
      ...
     <link rel="dx-theme" data-theme="generic.dark" href="css/dx.dark.css" data-active="false" />
   </head>
   ```

But my browser says:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/css/dx.dark.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

So my questions are:
How can i use the locale css files?
And why aren't the themes applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to build the project with `ng build --prod`. With `ng serve` or without production mode it doesn't work...